# Android 4.4.2 causes large file uploads to Amazon S3 to fail

Tags: android, http, amazon-s3, httpurlconnection

I am trying to upload large files (~ 200 MB) to Amazon S3. I am able to upload large files of 200 MB in size using Android 6 (Marshmallow), but it fails in devices using Android 4.4.2 (KitKat). In devices using Android 4.4.2, I can only upload files of up to 50 MB. For files above 50 MB it gives an OutOfMemoryError.

**Code:**

```
protected Void doInBackground(File... inputs) {

        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            file = inputs[0];  // the file path 
            java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
            long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
            milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 60; // Add 1 hour.
            expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);


            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, AppGlobal.deviceId + "/" + file.getName());
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);

            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType("application/octet-stream");


            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            bufferSize = 1024*100; //100 k


            final URL url = Util.getS3Client(UploadActivity.this).generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);


            String domain = AppGlobal.getDomain(UploadActivity.this);
            int port = Integer.valueOf(AppGlobal.getPort(UploadActivity.this));
            String signature = AppGlobal.getSignature(UploadActivity.this);


            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                    InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(domain, port));//the proxy server(Can be your laptop ip or company proxy)

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);


            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"); 
            // Proxy-Auth header
            String headerVal = String.format("%s:%s", "vzServices", signature);
            byte[] data = headerVal.getBytes("UTF-8");

            connection.addRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP));

            output = connection.getOutputStream();

            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            int c = 0;

            int bytes = 0;

            while ((c = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0) {
                System.out.println("read bytes :" + c);
                output.write(buffer, 0, c);
                bytes+=c;
                System.out.println("write bytes :" + bytes);

            }

            output.flush();
            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            success = true;
            buffer = null;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            try{
                if(output != null){
                    output.close();
                    output = null;

                }
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            try{
                if(inputStream != null){
                    inputStream.close();
                    inputStream = null;
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                    connection = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the exception stack trace I get :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                                      at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
                                                                                      at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
                                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RetryableOutputStream.write(RetryableOutputStream.java:64)
                                                                                      at com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility.UploadActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:613)
                                                                                      at com.amazonaws.demo.s3transferutility.UploadActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:508)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Can someone kindly help me out ?

Comment: If I had to guess, the difference is not Android OS version, but the amount of heap space your app has on each device, which may vary. You may have better luck using an HTTP API that directly supports submitting a file, such as OkHttp3. [This recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-file) shows doing that for a POST request (via `psot()`), but I think there is a PUT option as well.

Comment: Thanks !!! using OkHttp3 I resolved the "out of memory" exception.